# Как удалить ссылки на php?

Tags: php, парсер

Беру информацию с другого сайта таким макаром.

```
$content = file_get_contents
```

Получаю текст с ссылками вида

```
<a href="player.asp?id=31" title="???">Имя</a>
<a href="stats.asp?sortB=8&amp;dirB=2">Фамилия</a>
```

Как удалить ссылки и оставить только текст? (Имя Фамилия)

Пробовал как-то так, не получается, ссылки разные.

```
$content = str_replace('<a href="','', $content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тестировал на PHP 7.2, работает как надо

```
<?php

$links = [
    '<a href="player.asp?id=31" title="???">Имя</a>',
    '<a href="stats.asp?sortB=8&amp;dirB=2">Фамилия</a>'
];

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo preg_replace('/\<a.*\>(.*)\<\/a\>/', '$1', $link) . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Regex101 https://regex101.com/r/2EZBRj/2

Для тех случаев когда у нас нет массива с ссылками

```
<?php

// исходник
$content = file_get_contents('file.html');

// ищем все ссылки
preg_match_all('/\<a.*?\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/s', $content, $links);

// очищаем текст от вложенных тэгов, переносов строк, пробелов и т.д
// получаем чистый текст 
foreach ($links[1] as $link) {
    $t = preg_replace('/[\s]{1,}/s', ' ', $link);
    $t = trim($t);
    $t = preg_replace('/\<.*?\>.*?\<\/.*?\>/', '', $t);
    $t = trim($t);
    echo $t . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Для того чтобы получить текст вместо ссылок

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('file.html');

// удаляем открывающие тэги
$content = preg_replace('/\<a.*?\>/s', '', $content);

// удаляем закрывающие тэги
$content = preg_replace('/<\/a\>/s', '', $content);

// выводим на экан
echo $content;
```

Comment: Не получается. Мне нужно писать так? `foreach ($content as $link) {`

Comment: сейчас дополню!

Comment: Вообще все теги удаляются. Как только `<a href...` удалить?

Comment: блин я просто вопрос неправильно понял, от и нанес всякой чепухи, дополнил ответ как удалить тэги и оставить текст

Answer (score 0):

Дык вот же:

```
echo strip_tags($content);
```

Comment: Так вообще вся разметка удаляется, Нужно только ссылки

Comment: @steep значит вопрос задал не корректно "получаю текст с ссылками". Ну у strip_tags можно еще добавить allowable_tags, в некоторых случаях хватает.